# Android: Is There A Way To Wait Until A Fragment Attaches To An Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So Adopting The Design Pattern described here whereby a Async Task wrapped around a retained fragment via the setRetainInstance as seen described here

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Im having an issue where a task is started before the worker fragment can attach to the activity leaving the mCallBack to be null at the same time onPreExecute is called which throws a nullPointerException/

This is largely due to the fact that the async task is started via a method call (a start method which creates an instance of the inner async task) and not inside onCreate or OnActivityCreated since the task can be started again (under a new instance of it) and cannot be done so in onCreate or OnActivity created since the life cycle of these methods only call 1 time because of the setRetainInstance as far I as know.

My question is where a way to program some sort of routine whereby a wait until fragment has attached to activity routine and if so do the task that you need to do?

Many thanks.

**Update1: Code Posted**

This is how the worker fragment is being added. When the user presses the send feedback button. This OnClick Listener is invoked. The final if statement you see is what starts the async task. Note that this code is inside another fragment.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    mThreadFragment = (ConnectToServerForResults) fm.findFragmentByTag(ConnectToServerForResults.class.getName());

    if(mThreadFragment == null)
    {
        mThreadFragment = new ConnectToServerForResults();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(mThreadFragment, ConnectToServerForResults.class.getName()).commit();
    }


    if(!mThreadFragment.isRunning())
    {
        mThreadFragment.startSendFeedBack(3, preventSQLInjections(),getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    }
    else
    {
                //Work in progress :D
    }

}
```

**Worker Fragment Start Task Method**

```
public void startSendFeedBack(int requestCode,String feedback,String appName)
{
    XAMPP_URL ="http://10.0.2.2/testStuff/feed.php";
    http = new HTTPConnection();
    http.execute(String.valueOf(requestCode),XAMPP_URL,feedback,appName);
    mRunning = true;
}
```

**Worker Fragment OnAttach**

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Log.d("ERSEN", "onAttach");
        if(!(activity instanceof ResultAsyncTaskCallbacks))
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("activity must implement the AsyncTaskCallbacks interface.");
        }

        mCallback = (ResultAsyncTaskCallbacks) activity;



    }
```

Comment: All of the method invocations against mCallbacks in the article you posted are surrounded by null checks. How are you getting a NullPointerException? Also, how and where are you starting the background task? You can add some logic in your TaskFragment to ensure the task only starts after onAttach has been called.

Comment: can you post some codes? how do you start the asynctask and how do you add your fragment to your activity?

Comment: Hi. I added some code. @Karakuri, I do not have the null checks that surround mCallbacks being invoked.

Comment: @Karakuri, could you explain to me the logic you mentioned that I could add in myTaskFragment to ensure the task only starts after onAttach has been called

Comment: Use a boolean `isAttached` that you set to true in `onAttach` and false in `onDetach`. Make another boolean `pending`. When you tell the fragment to start working, if `isAttached` is false, set `pending` to true. On the next attach, if `pending` is true, start the task and set `pending` to false.

Comment: @Karakuri,thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I made a solution which solved the problems. May not be the best solution but my problems appear resolved.

I added a call back to my interface called onThreadFragmentAttached()

```
public static interface ResultAsyncTaskCallbacks
{
    void onPreExecuteResults();
    void onCancelledResults();
    void onPostExecuteResults();
    void onThreadFragmentAttached();
}
```

I added a class variable to the worker fragment

```
private boolean isFirstTime=true;
```

This Boolean at the start says that the fragment is being added for the first time

In OnActivityCreated I can safely assume that the fragment is attached because this is what that method signifies.

In there is this logic. Check if firstTime is true (yes would be if the fragment is added for the first time). If call onThreadFragmentAttached();. Set firstTime to false because the fragment is added. This false is preserved through config changes because this fragment is retained.

```
if(isFirstTime == true)
{
    mCallback.onThreadFragmentAttached();
    isFirstTime = false;
}
```

In main activity which implements the callbacks

```
@Override
    public void onThreadFragmentAttached(int fragmentCode) 
    {
        FB = (FeedBack)fragmentManger.findFragmentByTag(FeedBack.class.getName());
    FB.sendFeedback();
}
```

Find the feedback fragment (this was my fragment which needed to start a task) and call sendFeedBack method.

This is the method which simply calls the start method.

```
public void sendFeedback()
    {
        mThreadFragment.startSendFeedBack(3, preventSQLInjections(),getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    }
```

In my onClick I have the following logic

```
//Check if there is not a task running at the moment
        if(!mThreadFragment.isRunning()) //No task
        {
            //if its the first time worker fragment is being added it will start the task itself via the onThreadFragmentAttached callback (inside main activity) which then calls the sendFeedBack method that starts the task
            if(mThreadFragment.getIsFirstTime() != true) //this is here in cases where the thread fragment is already attached and the task can be started as normal.
            {
                sendFeedback();
            }   
        }
```

This checks if the fragment has already been added and just to go ahead and start the task. Note the getIsFirstTime method just returns the value of the class variable isFirstTime. If its false proceed as normal because its already attached. if it was true this would be bypassed and the task would start anyway via the onThreadAttachedCallback();